# How to print a smiley face character in assembly?

Tags: assembly, character-encoding, x86, dos, tasm

What are the lines of code to output a smiley face character in assembly (TASM)?

I know in order to print a dot, it requires:

```
MOV AH, 2
DL, '.'
INT 21h
```

and in order to print backspace,

```
MOV AH, 6
MOV DL, 8
INT 21H
```

How about a smiley face? I know it exists because it appears when there are garbage values.

Comment: But I can't control how such characters appear as garbage values.

Comment: [http://www.jimprice.com/ascii-dos.gif](http://www.jimprice.com/ascii-dos.gif) there you go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DOS [codepage 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP437) (and most others) the white smiley face is code #1, and the black one is code #2. So these are the values you need to put into `DL`.

```
MOV AH, 6
MOV DL, 1; print ☺
INT 21H
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look here http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html
where they give a good enough explanation of what interrupts do.

The important thing to notice here is that by loading a value on AH, you are effectively selecting the function that run. So MOV AH,2 MOV AH,6 and MOV AH,9 are all effectively selecting different functions.
In your case, either AH,2  or AH,6 should be good.

Now DL is the argument that you are passing to the function. In this case the function expects an argument which contains the ASCII value that it will print.

Hence, MOV DL,1 for the smiley face.